# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '188025671;Платёж;19\xa0ноя\xa02022;;;;;100;90'

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

Хочу сделать heatmap по таблице выгруженной из VK (там содержится информация о людях, оформивших платную подписку на vk donut). [image: Таблица]

Написал такой код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (4, 8) 

import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Users\\berna\\Desktop\\vkstat\\donut.csv')
import seaborn
seaborn.heatmap(data)
```

Возникает ошибка: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '188025671;Платёж;19\xa0ноя\xa02022;;;;;100;90'

Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нужно в read_csv указать разделитель точку с запятой.

Comment: @insolor, большое спасибо! Не могли бы Вы подсказать, куда именно нужно поставить ; ? Я только недавно начал заниматься питоном и всё для меня ново. Невдуплёныш, скажем так

Comment: `data = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Users\\berna\\Desktop\\vkstat\\donut.csv', sep=";")`

Comment: @insolor Теперь возникла еще одна проблема: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Платёж'

Comment: Ну вам для heatmap видимо не всю таблицу нужно передавать, а только данные. Это уже смотрите примеры по этой функции.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо большое! Буду разбираться!